# Security around remote access for Quartz.net Scheduler

Tags: c#, security, quartz.net

We are currently looking for a scheduling application to integrate within our solution. We are very close to locking in Quartz.net, but there is one deal breaker that I cannot find any resolution for on either Stackoverflow or Google.

The issue is around remote access via the API, e.g:

```
NameValueCollection properties = new NameValueCollection();
properties["quartz.scheduler.instanceName"] = "instanceName";
properties["quartz.scheduler.proxy"] = "true";
properties["quartz.scheduler.proxy.address"] = "tcp://localhost:555/QuartzScheduler";

ISchedulerFactory sf = new StdSchedulerFactory(properties);
IScheduler sched = sf.GetScheduler();
```

We currently understand that any user could use code similar to the above, and then use the scheduler instance to manage / alter / add jobs, etc. The problem is, we would need to restrict this access (as the user context that this runs in has access to sensitive information).

In our ideal case we would like to lock down remote access to specified users. This would allow authorised users to manage Quartz from an interface. If this is not possible then we would be after a solution that locked down remote access without breaking the ability to access the API from the same machine (the drawback being users would need to log onto the server to administer quartz).

I'd be quite surprised if ours was the first organisation to have this requirement, how have others solved this problem?

Answer (score 2):

In short there is no authentication/authorization scheme built-in.

First of all, even if malicious user could gain access to interface (seems like an unsafe network to me if people are hostile) this individual could only manage the *scheduler*. So the information that could be disclosed is job/trigger names and groups. User could maliciously trigger job to run that is not coded robust enough to survive running more often that initially expected.

The outside party could not gain access to what jobs are allowed to do, this includes the connection strings etc or actual job logic. Outside party would also be unable to add more jobs that are not present on server's bin directory - so the jobs are locked and no surprises could actually happen.

One single thing that does come to mind is that user could schedule native job with parameters to do something harmful on system running with services permissions.

One way to get around this is to have simple controlling interface like web service/web application that would take care of permissions etc and would connect to localhost's windows service that is otherwise firewalled.

Comment: Thanks Marko, interesting. Regarding the network, in the industry I work in we can't rely on the security of the network, we have to look at security in layers. So even if the network is safe, we might have to deal with unhappy employees, or breaches, etc, etc. We may have to explore the idea of wrapping Quartz in a service.